# How to adjust the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable, while running ./configure

Tags: linux, installation, centos

I'm running into this error message while trying to install from a tarball

```
configure: error: Package requirements (gtk+-2.0 >= 2.16.0) were not met:

No package 'gtk+-2.0' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.
```

Following command gives me the location of GTK

```
$ whereis gtk-2.0

gtk-2: /etc/gtk-2.0 /usr/lib64/gtk-2.0
```

My question is how to adjust PKG_CONFIG_PATH, many of the online tutorials did not make much sense to me. I'm running centos 6.4

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$> env PKG_CONFIG_PATH=... ./configure
```

fill `...` with whatever you need / want.

but ... the error message `No package gtk+-2.0 found` indicates that you are missing the c++-bindings for gtk2. `whereis gtk-2.0` only shows you that you have gtk2 installed.

Comment: Thanks for your help akira, another thing is what package do i need to have c++ bindings, and i'm assuming the path ...../configure would be /usr/lib64/gtk-2.0 ??

Comment: MyGNU, did you find what library is needed for c++ bindings?